Enabling HTTP 2.0 to origin when using Elastic Load Balancer
We are dealing with a scenario where CloudFront is being used as a CDN with a public CA SSL cert with ELB origin. The ELB has https certificate same as CloudFront and HTTPS listener with target group configured for HTTPS with HTTP1 protocol version. The ECS tasks have running https 2.0 with self signed certs which have been verified.
The issue is, when HTTPS is enabled with HTTP 2.0 on the ELB, CloudFront returns a 502. As soon as the protocol version is reverted to HTTP1 on the ELB, the page loads through cloudfront but the requests that are received by ECS tasks are HTTPS 1.1.
Given that this is an ELB origin capable of HTTP 2.0, is there any way to connect to known origin with HTTP 2.0? I am aware that for custom origins for CloudFront always uses http 1.1. TIA!
